# Asp net chart control - showing only dates that exist in data source (hiding empty dates)

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, bar-chart

I have a chart in an ASP.Net Web Form (Visual Studio) connected to a SQL server database table. 
Y-values: electricity consumption
X-values: date and time

The user selects the interval he wants to see. These values are used by a stored procedure to create a temp table. This temp table is used to create the chart.

[Easy example of table after user action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwb8r.png)

[Corresponding chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkMYx.png)

I just want to see the bars with table values. 
In other words: I don't want to display points that don't have table values.

I tried playing around with the 'empty points' settings in chart control, no results
. 
I also tried setting the x-axis datatype to a string, which didn't make any difference.

I searched high and low for a solution but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever has the same problem:

I got it to work by converting the dates to varchar in my SQL server table!

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giAAa.png)